# Save data to DB using JQuery ajax on button click

Tags: c#, jquery, webmethod

Here is my Jquery ajax method:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("input[id$='btnBulten']").click(function () {
        //alert("dd");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://URL/Controls/EBulten.ascx/EBultenSend",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{nameSurname:" + $("input['id$='$txtNameSurname']").val() + " }",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("Mesajınız başarıyla iletildi");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and in codebehind code:

```
 [WebMethod()]
public static void EBultenSend(string nameSurname, string email, string IP, string position, string firmName)
{
    int bultenId = EBulten.InsertEbulten(nameSurname, email, IP, position, firmName);
}
```

InsertEBulten calling SP to save data to DB. All parameters comes from TextBoxes. I am not able to save data to database.How can I fix this?
Normally, without WebMethod, if I use this method on client click, it inserts data to DB.

Comment: Have you identified that the problem is on the server side? Do you get any data from the client? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @user707727 As I edited, I can insert data to DB without WebMethod, but requirement changed so I need to use it.

Comment: Did you try to debug to see if webmethod is called ? How did you annotate your class of your webmethod ?

Comment: I found that **ascx** Control is not possible to use, because it does not represent URL.So I will change it to aspx.